# Cloud foundry installation on a centos VM(VMware)

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible to install cloud foundry for centos on a virtual machine with centos installed?.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer depends on the purpose of the request.

If you just want to have a test/dev CF environment for local use - it is better to spin up PCF dev (https://pivotal.io/pcf-dev) using VirtualBox.

If you are looking for deployment of production scale Cloud Foundry instance then it would be a question of deploying Bosh director instance and then deploying multi-vm configuration Cloud Foundry configuration with VMware CPI (for deployment on ESX based private clouds)

Comment: That's great info.

Comment: I am looking for CF deployment for an application deployment for my use only.all I have is a centos VM on VMware.IaaS layer is not there.Can we install IaaS layer on top of the VM or we can only install on top of a physical machine?. Pardon my ignorance.Am a newbie

Comment: Yes, you can use VMware IaaS for cloud foundry installation.

E.g. install bosh director on your VMware IaaS with VMware CPI back to your IaaS and install CloudFoundry using bosh - it will create multi VM CF install inside your VMware IaaS.